# Start service command failed after deployment

Tags: c#, windows-services, castle-windsor, topshelf

I've got an issue with a Windows service - after deployment when `service_Start` is attempted it fails (times out). On the second attempt it mostly succeeds. 
I've tried increasing the timeout but it did not help.
The service has no dependencies.

It's a `c#` + `Topshelf (latest)` application which uses `Castle.Windsor (2.5.3)` container.
The main class implementing `IMyService` is registered with the lifestyleType `Singleton`.
Other dependencies are registered as `transient`.

The service is reading messages off a Rabbit bus and storing them in Couchbase.

The configuration code looks like this:

```
HostFactory.Run(x =>                                 
            {
                x.Service<IMyService>(s =>                        
                {
                    s.ConstructUsing(name => WindsorContainerContext.Container.Resolve<IMyService>());   
                    s.WhenStarted(s => s.Start());             
                    s.WhenStopped(s =>
                                    {
                                        s.Stop();
                                        WindsorContainerContext.Container.Release(s);
                                        WindsorContainerContext.Container.Dispose();
                                    });
                });
                x.RunAsLocalSystem();                            

                x.SetDescription(serviceDescription);
                x.SetDisplayName(serviceDescription);                       
                x.SetServiceName(serviceName);

            });
```

I thought that maybe something does not get released properly and causes the start up to fail but after having tried a few changes I don't really have ideas what else to try.

I know this might not be enough to get this solved - do let me know what sort of information would be helpful. I would really like to find out what is going on here, so I'd also appreciate if you can point me in the right direction in terms of debugging this.

Comment: You seems to be having no issue in terms of permission as the service works as expected on the second attempt.  I would suggest you to debug the start method of the service because normally the time out is caused by the code in this method.

Comment: @Kokulan - I'm not quite sure how to make it fail when debugging, I wasn't able to get any failures in debug mode until now. The start method starts a new task which starts consuming messages from the bus and saving them to Couchbase. There's not much to it, all is nicely wrapped in try/catch blocks, so whatever exceptions happen they should be handled

Comment: You could log the activity and time to a log file in the start method. I normally write major activities in the start method to log file and see what happened as it is not easy to catch all during debug. You could compare the log of first time and subsequent start. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

So as a console app, normal debugging, you won't normally timeout.

So you can request more time, but I'd start with requesting like 20-30 seconds. If you ask for too much time the service manager just ignores your request and doesn't tell you.